# Oracle SQL: how to pass sysdate in path of XMLTable

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmltable

I am retrieving data from xml for insert into table. But I also want to insert an additional data sysdate in to following xmltable table:

```
sample XML data:
<employee_info>                             
<employee_id>ID1234</employee_id>
<name>John</name>
</employee_info>

-- This is the query Notice at  CREATED_ON :

INSERT INTO TBL_EMPLOYEE TBL (TBL.EMP_ID, TBL.Name, TBL.Created_on) 
    SELECT x.* FROM XMLTABLE('/employee_info'
                        PASSING xmlData
                        COLUMNS  EMP_ID  VARCHAR2(10)     PATH   'employee_id',                                                        
                                 Name    VARCHAR2(50)     PATH    'name',                                                                                        
                                 CREATED_ON DATE     PATH '<created_on>sysdate</created_on>');
```

How can I pass the `sysdate` on column `CREATED_ON` that is not part of the given xml sample. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to operate on xml level to have column with sysdate:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_employee tbl
     (tbl.emp_id
     ,tbl.name
     ,tbl.created_on)
SELECT t.emp_id, t.name, sysdate
  FROM xmltable('/employee_info' 
                passing xmldata 
                columns 
                        emp_id VARCHAR2(10) path 'employee_id', 
                        NAME VARCHAR2(50) path 'name'
               ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin Wroblewski